# Can't access dynamically generated element with Jquery and Jsoup

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, jsoup

lets explain whats happening, i am parsing a html page to show its content in my android application. firstly i load the html with android `webview` and then i get html code by code below :

```
  // load a webview
         wb.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));

    // on page finish i will call a   @JavascriptInterface
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

     view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processMain(
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);");

        }




          @JavascriptInterface
         class LoadListener{
                @JavascriptInterface
                public void processMain(String html)
                {

                     doc= Jsoup.parse(html);
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                   //here i can parse doc that is a jsoup document and select elements
        doc.select("#login > tbody > tr > td.error").text();
                    });
```

my problem : there is a `table` in my html page that is dynamically added to html( i am not sure how, append ? addchild ? php ? or... because i have not access to php codes ). i select that table with this line of code! **but it returns null.**

```
doc.select("#login > tbody > tr > td.error").text()
```

so how can i select that table ??

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup is not a browser. It is a parser. It does not understand JavaScript and can't run it. So if your page dynamically constructs DOM elements through Javascript you can't access this with Jsoup. Have a look into [selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)  if you need this

Comment: you are right jsoup cant!  but  i am parsing the result of selecting entire page with a javascript `view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processMain(
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);");
` then parse it with jsoup ! my question is  javascript cant select dynamically generated element too ?

Comment: Oh, then JSoup should be able to parse this. can you please share the generated HTML that you try to parse?